# Bootstrap Popup open using url params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
 <a class="activate_button" href="{{w.LandingPageURL}}" ng-click="newwindow(w)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{w.CouponID}}">DEAL</a>  

<div class="modal fade coupon_popup" id="{{w.CouponID}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="{{w.CouponID}}" aria-hidden="true">
```

I am trying to open popup using url params.

For example  my url `www.dadad/asdada#{{w.CouponID}}`

then need to open that id popup. I am using bootstrap.js v3.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a JavaScript code like this,

```
var x=location.hash.substring(1);
$('#myModal').attr({"id": x},{"aria-labelledby":x}); 
$('#'+x).modal();
```

No changes in HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/h5t89my3/3/show/light/#aaa)

Comment: I try this but popup not take dynamically means it show every time same popup.

Comment: Yes, you are changing the popup id means, it loads the same popup. or else stop changing the popup id and call only `$('#'+x).modal();`

Comment: what you say? can you please describe .My id is dynamic.

Comment: Then you need to have multiple Popups. and based on the Url, call the required popup. just skip the second line of my js code. and then pass the popup id in url

Comment: when my url www.sasas/asas#678 then i try to show id 678 popup. I am try this `var x=location.hash.substring(1);$('#'+x).modal();` but it not work

Comment: then there should be a popup with id 678

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/h5t89my3/4/, 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/h5t89my3/4/show/light/#678

Comment: if it is not showing some thine else went wrong, see the sample link i provided, my code is working

Comment: I am using angular js for data binding so i try to make it on (document).ready .But it not work

Comment: try your code like this `angular.element(document).ready(function () {your code here});`

Comment: would you please post your code. better if you can setup a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap modal popup means:

Use iframe in your modal popup and pass the url to it.

If you are opening new popup window means:

Use this

```
var url = 'www.dadad/asdada#{{w.CouponID}}';
window.open(url, 'Title', 'width=900px,height=900px,left=50px,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
```